# How to share screen to a group in Linux Mint/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, skype

My colleagues use Mint OS and cannot share his screen to the team via TeamViewer (he can only do it on 1 vs 1 sharing).

Is there a way to archive that similarly in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself in this [list](http://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/?platform=linux&license=free) and the interesting candidates to me are [migoko](http://www.mikogo.com/) and [yuuguu](http://www.yuuguu.com/home)